# understanding server structure

Tags: linux, apache, filesystems, centos, dedicated-server

I have recently purchased a dedicated server with apache on centOS. I want to understand the complete file structure in the server. I am accessing it through putty shell prompt.

What i need to understand is that how the files are stored and where. Like through WHM i am able to login to cpanel and create subdomains etc. And through ftp, i can put contents in that subdomain directory.

Now how do i access those directories for subdomains? How the individual website accounts are stored? I want to get a clear picture of the complete system through shell. I just now prefer using shell to view the file system hierarchy. any help would be really great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most/many Linux distributions adhere to a standard layout called FHS - File System Hierarchy Standard.  That lays out some of the ground rules around where major things go - things like /etc for configuration and /var for things that, well, vary.

The most relevant thing you probably care about is that apache's config information is somewhere in /etc/httpd, the actual HTML files are in /var/www and the logs are in /var/log.

http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-filesystem-fhs.html.

[How to list the contents of a package using YUM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104055/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-package-using-yum) will show you where the apache package puts things by default.

Note that all of this is just convention - if you install apache from source you can put everything where you like, but it may confuse other people that have to support your box.