# repoquery gives no output for a package even though the package is installed (yum-utils)

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm, yum

Ref. existing question [How to list the contents of a package using YUM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104055/how-to-list-the-contents-of-a-package-using-yum) and its answers.

As shown below, repoquery (from yum-utils package) gives no output for a package even though the package is installed. In fact, the package in question is yum-utils, from whence repoquery came! (Though note that it also gives no output for other packages - an example is shown.)

Does anybody know why this is happening? Has anybody else had the same problem?

Problem is as follows...

The repoquery command from the yum-utils package doesn't appear to work as intended. See below. yum-utils package was installed, repoquery command could then be used but it does not list the contents of the package it came from, although it does list contents for another package which I chose at random.

```
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ re
read         readonly     regdbdump    reset        restorecon
readarray    readprofile  reload       resize2fs    restorecond
readelf      reboot       rename       resizecons   return
readlink     refer        renice       restart      rev
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo yum install yum-utils
Loaded plugins: product-id, rhnplugin, subscription-manager
Updating certificate-based repositories.
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package yum-utils.noarch 0:1.1.30-30.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: yum >= 3.2.29-56 for package: yum-utils-1.1.30-30.el6                                                                                                 .noarch
--> Running transaction check
---> Package yum.noarch 0:3.2.29-22.el6 will be updated
---> Package yum.noarch 0:3.2.29-60.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

================================================================================
Package        Arch        Version             Repository                 Size
================================================================================
Installing:
yum-utils      noarch      1.1.30-30.el6       rhel-x86_64-server-6      110 k
Updating for dependencies:
yum            noarch      3.2.29-60.el6       rhel-x86_64-server-6      1.0 M

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)
Upgrade       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 1.1 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/2): yum-3.2.29-60.el6.noarch.rpm                      | 1.0 MB     00:00
(2/2): yum-utils-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch.rpm                | 110 kB     00:00
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                           619 kB/s | 1.1 MB     00:01
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Updating   : yum-3.2.29-60.el6.noarch                                     1/3
  Installing : yum-utils-1.1.30-30.el6.noarch                               2/3
  Cleanup    : yum-3.2.29-22.el6.noarch                                     3/3
Installed products updated.

Installed:
  yum-utils.noarch 0:1.1.30-30.el6

Dependency Updated:
  yum.noarch 0:3.2.29-60.el6

Complete!
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ repo
repoclosure  repo-graph   repoquery    reposync
repodiff     repomanage   repo-rss     repotrack
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo repoquery --list freeradius
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo repoquery --list yum-utils   # NOTE NO OUTPUT HERE
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo rpm -qa | head
[sudo] password for jgilmartin:
ruby-libs-1.8.7.352-10.el6_4.x86_64
basesystem-10.0-4.el6.noarch
ruby-shadow-1.4.1-13.el6.x86_64
openssh-clients-5.3p1-94.el6.x86_64
s3cmd-1.0.1-1.el6.noarch
info-4.13a-8.el6.x86_64
procmail-3.22-25.1.el6.x86_64
libcom_err-1.41.12-11.el6.x86_64
dbus-1.2.24-7.el6_3.x86_64
libsepol-2.0.41-4.el6.x86_64
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo repoquery --list s3cmd | head   # WORKS FOR THIS PACKAGE
/usr/bin/s3cmd
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/ACL.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/ACL.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/AccessLog.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/AccessLog.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/BidirMap.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/BidirMap.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/CloudFront.py
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/CloudFront.pyc
/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/S3/Config.py
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo rpm -ql yum-utils | head   # rpm -ql WORKS FOR THE PACKAGE
/etc/bash_completion.d
/etc/bash_completion.d/yum-utils.bash
/usr/bin/debuginfo-install
/usr/bin/find-repos-of-install
/usr/bin/needs-restarting
/usr/bin/package-cleanup
/usr/bin/repo-graph
/usr/bin/repo-rss
/usr/bin/repoclosure
/usr/bin/repodiff
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ uname -a
Linux cnmvlmtlb01 2.6.32-220.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Nov 9 08:03:13 EST 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$
```

Comment: `repoquery` queries the repository for the list. `rpm -ql` uses the local rpmdb. If the repositories repoquery has metadata for don't contain that package (or its file list) it won't show anything. Try `sudo repoquery --disablerepo=* --list s3cmd` for example, that should also show no files. You could try rebuilding all the yum metadata (`yum clean all; yum makecache`) and seeing if that helps.

Comment: `repoquery` also doesn't require root to function (though it will use a per-user metadata cache instead of the root/system one when run as another user I believe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across this problem and resolved it by adding the option `--pkgnarrow=installed`.

I suspect repoquery is a little buggy in this regard. I found that some packages would appear even if they were installed, while others would not, unless I added the pkgnarrow option.

You could also use `--pkgnarrow=all`.

Example:

```
$ sudo repoquery --repoid ix-stable boost
$ sudo repoquery --repoid ix-stable --pkgnarrow=all boost
boost-0:1.41.0-17.el6_4.x86_64
```

Comment: That does indeed make the difference harmic. I agree there seems to be a bug here, as the man page states that 'repository' is the default for 'pkgnarrow' but actually if you try to use that, it says it's an unknown method - see below.

Comment: That does indeed make the difference harmic. I agree there seems to be a bug here, as the man page states that 'repository' is the default for 'pkgnarrow' but actually if you try to use that, it says it's an unknown method - see below.


`(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo repoquery --list yum-utils   # NOTE NO OUTPUT
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo repoquery --list yum-utils --pkgnarrow=all | head -1
/etc/bash_completion.d
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$ sudo repoquery --list yum-utils --pkgnarrow=repository
Unknown pkgnarrow method: repository
(DEV) [jgilmartin@cnmvlmtlb01 ~]$`