# Is it possible to have two different Perl versions?

Tags: perl, raku

Currently I have Perl 5.8.8. Can I update to Perl 6? I am using [Red Hat Linux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Linux) 5 OS. Is it possible to upgrade Perl on Red Hat Linux 5 or any other OS? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll try to articulate an answer that addresses all your requests, HTH:

- I wouldn't touch system Perl, because other system software might depend on a particular version. If you need a different version of Perl 5 for development, it's arguably better to install it in a controlled, isolated environment
- To do so you can use tools like [Perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/): with Perlbrew you can install distinct versions of Perl 5, and you'll be able to switch back and forth according to your development needs
- You say you want to "update to Perl 6". Perhaps you noticed I wrote *Perl 5* in the previous paragraphs. Perl 6 is not just a new version of Perl, but a profound evolution of the language: it stems from the same core principles, but it is quite different from its older sibling. Code written in Perl 5 won't run in Perl 6, for example

To sum up:

- You can have *both* Perl 5 and Perl 6 on your system, but they are distinct languages
- You can have multiple versions of Perl 5 using Perlbrew
- I would suggest not to tamper with the version of Perl distributed with the OS

Comment: Thanks larsen , the reson I am looking for a differenct version of Perl is that I want to work with Excel file in Perl (create , read and write )  but my system Perl that is v5.8.8 does not seem to have any module for that , Would you be able to tell since which module Perl5 included utility for Excel files?

Comment: As far as I know, Perl 5 distribution never included among the core modules a library parse/write Excel files. There are plenty on CPAN, tho': my personal favourite for writing Excel files (should I say I'm lucky that I seldom have to parse them?) is [Excel::Writer::XLSX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Excel::Writer::XLSX)

Comment: @Vicky There are [224 matches of 'excel'](https://metacpan.org/search?size=500&q=excel) among the 30,000+ free packages (170,000+ modules) on CPAN. One or more of these should do what you want to do. Use cpantesters to see whether a particular module that looks good "on paper" is likely to actually work out for you in practice. For example, I see 6 passes out of 6 for [Excel::Writer::XLSX tests on 5.8.8 in today's cpantester results](http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/E/Excel-Writer-XLSX.html).

Comment: @Vivky It's a good idea to tell people what you want to accomplish rather than how you are trying to do it. :)

Answer (score 7):

Perl 5 and Perl 6 are really different languages that share a name. Installing Perl 6 will not overwrite your Perl 5. I'm guessing that you don't want Perl 6 and instead want the latest version of Perl 5 ([v5.26 was just released](http://blogs.perl.org/users/sawyer_x/2017/05/perl-5260-is-now-available.html)). You might consider updating everything to something recently released, including your OS ;)

If you're curious what your package manager is going to install, you can see the list. Perhaps [How to list the contents of a package using YUM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/104055/2766176) is interesting for you.

Aside from the system's installed Perl 5, you can download, compile, and install other versions of Perl5 to any location you like. I have all the perls installed, for example, and the system perl is still there.