# Install tcmalloc on CentOS

Tags: c++, linux, centos, tcmalloc, google-perftools

I installed `tcmalloc` on CentOS using the command:

```
sudo yum install google-perftools
```

And it proceeds correctly. But I cannot find any installed perftools libraries in `/usr/lib/`, so I cannot set `LD_PRELOAD` variable.

Then, when I tried to compile with flag `-ltcmalloc`, the compiler did not recognize it, which quite made sense.

What else should I specify to use `tcmalloc` on CentOS? Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a `tcmalloc (3)` man page? CentOS is pretty good about supplying docs and they are usually pretty good.

Comment: @jww no, there isn't one. `No manual entry for tcmalloc`.

Comment: According to [gperftools](https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) you link `-ltcmalloc` or `-ltcmalloc_minimal`. But I can't find it searching in `/lib` or `/lib64` (`find /lib64 -name '*tcmalloc*'`).

Comment: @jww I tried that, but I got `/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltcmalloc`

Comment: [`dnf repoquery -l gperftools`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/107520/608639) shows the package is empty. It sucks to be you right about now :)

Comment: @jww Thanks man. I guess I have to build from source then.

Comment: Lets see if anything interesting drops out from [Fedora package contains no files?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/465857/56041)

Comment: @jww I really appreciate that! Hope we could figure this out.

Answer (score 3):

The package names have changed a little. Just run:

```
yum install gperftools gperftools-devel
```

...and you'll find various libtcmalloc files in /usr/lib64/

Comment: The package `gperftools-libs` provides only the tcmalloc library if you don't need the rest of the tools and their (numerous) dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

You can always build from source. I have done that with my centos 8.

Source code can be found here: https://github.com/google/tcmalloc. Be aware you will need bazel for building the project.

Comment: Please note that this repository is maintained by Google and is not exactly the same as gperftools (https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools) which is maintained by the community (projects have forked).