# Install tcmalloc from source to link without bazel?

Tags: c++, linux, bazel, tcmalloc, google-perftools

I'd like to install tcmalloc from source.

I'm on centos8. I'd install from yum but don't see any `google-perf` or `gperf` or anything of the sort [available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52103646/install-tcmalloc-on-centos). (I did do `yum check-update`.)

The instructions on the [tcmalloc github](https://github.com/google/tcmalloc/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md) sure are simple. Install `bazel` (check). Then run `bazel test //tcmalloc/...` in the `<projectroot>/tcmalloc` dir. Then, it claims, "Congratulations! You've installed TCMalloc"!

Ok tcmalloc team, love you guys, but... I think our definitions of `install` are different. I don't see any bit of `libtcmalloc` available in `/usr/lib/` or `/usr/lib64/` or anywhere else for that matter.

How do I get a nice, plain, old shared library outputted by this bazel beast? Linking in via bazel to my project as described is *not* an option.

Comment: It is named [gperftools-devel](https://centos.pkgs.org/8/epel-x86_64/gperftools-devel-2.7-6.el8.x86_64.rpm.html). Also you will need to add EPEL repository (`yum install epel-release`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes @dewaffled had the answer in the comments. Here is what I used.

`yum install -y epel-release && yum install -y gperftools.x86_64`

Or you can use the `gperftools-devel` that @dewaffled mentioned.